# SSIS can't stop debug execution task script task

Tags: c#, ssis

How can I stop the script task execution while debugging?
If I use the button 'Stop debug', It still continues to run...
Thanks

Comment: Put a breakpoint on a line in the script.

Comment: I can debug cause I inserted a breakpoing into the script

Comment: Remove the breakpoint and hit F5. Sometimes your VS will close and return to BIDS, sometimes it will not close before the task has been completed successfully or before it has failed successfully. That's the way SSIS-development works :) (Note that the breakpoint will still be set, if you remove it in debug mode.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Debug menu, choose Terminate All.

Comment: Thanks! Task is blocked

Answer (score 0):

Clicking **Stop Debug** will stop your task. However, it may take some time for the script task to actually stop what it's doing, especially if you are performing a large database operation and it needs to get rolled back.

Comment: I observed that the task does not end until the end of the script,
still performs all instructions.